# Alternative to dips when no suitable "equipment" available to do dips?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, dips

I've been following Nerd Fitness's bodyweight program, starting with the [beginner](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/12/09/beginner-body-weight-workout-burn-fat-build-muscle/) exercises and having built some muscle, now starting to add some of the [advanced](http://www.nerdfitness.com/blog/2009/12/17/advanced-body-weight-workout-warning-this-will-kick-your-ass/) exercises.

Among the advanced exercises are [Dips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dip_%28exercise%29), for which I don't have any suitable equipment, or bar stools, as suggested in the exercise description.

Is there another exercise I can replace the Dips with to get the same workout?

Comment: You can do chest dips on a counter-top corner if you have one of those

Comment: Gymnastic rings; $30 and you just need a tree branch or rafter.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you try to reach with dips.

If you want to hit the triceps, you can do some pushup variations, e.g. diamond pushups.
If you'd like to hit your chest, then it's a little bit difficult.
Maybe this video gives you some hints (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ALg8W4xxmSk).

Just for the case that you haven't thought of installing rings on your ceiling:
This would be a great improvement for your bodyweight career.

Comment: That's a good question. I haven't really contemplated exactly which exercise hits what in the training program. Based on the other exercises using the arms, pull- chin-  and push-ups, what _should_ I want to hit with the dips?

Comment: Personally I use dips for the chest development. You'll have to consider that a compound movement always have other muscles in touch. Therefore I have also a triceps involvement inside my chest dips, but not as main focus.
You can involve more triceps activity with an upright torso.